# Whatever happened to Barthes' "science of literature"?

Tags: theory, literary-criticism, roland-barthes, criticism-and-truth

In *Criticism and Truth* (*Critique et Vérité*, 1966), Roland Barthes puts forward what we might call a manifesto for both a science of literature on the one hand, and of literary criticism on the other:

- Criticism is about **how** to approach a literary work, it is "the **intention** of giving a particular meaning to the work", while
- The literary science should be concerned with **establishing methods to study literary meaning**, or as Barthes puts it, to "describe [the] **logic** [by which] meanings are engendered in a manner which is capable of being accepted by the **symbolic logic** of humankind".

In Barthes' terminology, we could say a critique is a certain "discourse" ("une parole parmi d'autres") given to the science of literature. Therefore the science needs to provide the critic with the **tools**, with the **methods** to perform his task. See for example the following excerpts from *Criticism and Truth*:

> Faced with the impossibility of mastering all the sentences of a language, the linguist is satisfied to establish a **hypothetical model of description** which allows him to explain how
> the infinity of sentences in a language is generated. Whatever corrections one might be led to make, there is no reason not to try to apply such a **method** to works of literature: these works are themselves like immense "sentences" derived from the general language of symbols through **a
> certain number of set transformations** or in a more general way through **a certain logic of meaning** which will have **to be described**.
>
> [...]
>
> This science will have two important areas, according to the signs it is dealing with; the first area will include **those signs which are shorter than the sentence**, such as the figures of antiquity, phenomena of connotation, "semantic anomalies", etc., in a word all of the characteristics of literary language as a whole; the second area will deal with **signs which are longer than the sentence**, those parts of discourse from which one can infer a structure of the narrative, of the poetic message, of the discursive text, etc. Large and small units of discourse obviously exist in a relationship of integration (like phonemes in relation to words and words in relation to the sentence), but they are made up of levels which exist independently of description.

Barthes finishes his chapter on the literary science by stating that "**a long road remains to be travelled** before we shall have at our disposal a linguistics of discourse, that is to say a true science of literature in conformity with the verbal nature of its object".

55 years later, **did we ever got (close) to a science of literature in the way Barthes intended it to be? What methodological and theoretical developments followed which can be traced back to this manifesto, or which are in the spirit of it, in Barthes' own oeuvre or in that from other authors?**

My question is motivated by the fact that, while Barthes' view on criticism is self-explanatory (because criticism is about "intention"), the science of literature is about method, and therefore a manifesto is insufficient to fully grasp its nature. Said otherwise, I am interested in **examples** of what could be called literary science in Barthes' sense.

**Edit 13-Dec-2021:**
It seems to me Barthes oeuvre has multiple example of his criticism approach, but I am not sure whether he wrote methodology-oriented texts towards a science of literature:

- On the criticism side, Barthes' oeuvre contains multiple examples of his approach such as *On Racine* (*Sur Racine*, 1963) or *S/Z* (1970), including works not circumscribed to literature such as *Mythologies* (1957), *The Rhetoric of the Image* (*Rhétorique de l'image*, 1964) or *Empire of Signs* (*L'Empire des signes*, 1970) but which are useful to understand his ideas.
- However, on the science side, the only work I can think of are his *Elements of Semiology* (*Éléments de sémiologie*, 1964), written 2 years prior to *Criticism and Truth* so this was evidently a tentative first step: Barthes himself writes that his *Elements* are intended at:

> "[**Starting**] semiological research on its way. [...] We are merely suggesting and elucidating **a terminology** in the hope that it may enable an **initial** (albeit **provisional**) order [...]".

Comment: Interesting question. (Note: on this site, I wouldn't say that "Barthes' view on criticism is self-explanatory (because criticism is about "intention")", since many people here probably still believe in the importance of authorial intent, whereas Barthes talks of literary criticism "giving a particular meaning to the work" (as opposed to deriving it from the text or the author).)

Comment: Thank you @Tsundoku. I meant to say that, because criticism is about your mindset when approaching a work, Barthes' manifesto could be sufficient to understand it, while on the other hand the manifesto is insufficient for the science of literature, which at some point requires a proper methodological corpus. My undercurrent thinking was also that Barthes oeuvre has examples of applied criticism, while I am not sure if there are examples of attempts towards this science of literature - I've edited accordingly.